# iOS - Pop two or more controllers but don't the top

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following scenario:

```
A(Bottom) -> B -> C -> D(Top)
```

Once I'm on the top (D controller) I want to pop B and C controller. On this way when I press back from D I can to A.

**It is even posible?**

Comment: Is `A` your `First screen` or `rootView`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you need change navigation stack after push to `D viewController` implement this

```
NSMutableArray *navigationStack = [D.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[navigationStack removeObject:B];
[navigationStack removeObject:C];
[D.navigationController setViewControllers:navigationStack animated:NO];
```

And after you pop back you will return to A

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this to pop from D to A.

```
navCon.popToViewController(navCon.viewControllers[navCon.viewControllers.count - 4], animated: true)
```

Or if you have a reference to A

```
navCon.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: This way will pop C and B. I don't want to see the animation of C and B are popped. I want to see the animation when pop D goes to A.

Comment: @Ricardo Did you test it? This does not show the animation of B and C.

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in self.navigationController!.viewControllers {
    // Filter for your desired view controller:
    if item.isKind(of: SchedulesViewController.self) { 
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(item, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in uinavigationcontroller that clean the navigation stack:
"– popToRootViewControllerAnimated:"
With this method, if you call it from D, you pop to A directly. 
If you want a more customized navigation like "I only want to pop the 2 previous controllers" or something like that, you have to build a stack like @iSashok did.